# is there an easy way to delete files (*.pdf and *.eps) from the git archives to make the archive smaller

Tags: git

I use git to control revisions of a latex document with pdf and eps images generated by gnuplot. i need pdf and eps in short term to look at changes quickly. but i don't need them in long term because i can generate them with latex and gnuplot from data files.

is there a way to remove *.pdf (all pdf) files from the archive (all commits in all branches)

Answer (score 0):

This common usecase is explained in details in a section of this chapter: http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html